# equivalent of import * as actions from 'actions' in require

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack

what is the equivalent of

```
import * as actions from 'actions';
```

in require using 1 line?

I know that I can use require to import 1 function

```
var eat = require('actions').eat;
```

Comment: `var actions = require('actions')`?